# Regex after character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use a regex to get the value after a character. In this case, the string is `m325` and I need to get whatever is after the `m`.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
Regex rgMeter = new Regex("m(.+$");
intMeterID = Convert.ToInt32(rgMeter.Match(strID));
```

**Update:**

Thanks for all your answers...for some reason the regex "m(.+)$" is returning the m as well as the string I require. I have tried the Groups example and it returns the data that I want. Why do I need to use Groups to do this?

Comment: can you show us the complete string.. are they in same line or in different lines

Comment: Do you have a matching closing parens in your regular expression or is that a typo?

Comment: @user517406 - If you want to update your question you can simply edit it. I've merged your additional comments that you provided as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the missing `)`, you oversimplified it a bit. You need to do

```
Regex rgMeter = new Regex("m(.+)$");
intMeterID = Convert.ToInt32(rgMeter.Match(strID).Groups[1].Value);
```

(Possibly, you might want to add a check if the `Match()` matched or not.)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing ). Plus, if you are extracting a number you should limit yourself to digits only, Will avoid trying to parse a faulty string into integer in the next statement.

```
m(\d*)
```

Answer (score 1):

"m(.+)$" - there wasn't closed (

Answer (score 1):

The regex you require is `/^m(.*)$/`

Actually you should use `\d` or `[0-9]` if you want match digits.

```
/^m([0-9]*)$/
```

and

```
/^m([0-9]{3})$/
```

if there are always 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can test it on: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

What values can appear behind the "m" character?
If it's only an integer, the I should use the solution Shekhar_Pro provided..
If any character, go with the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the closing `)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple "m\d*" should do this.. please show us whole string to see the case.